# Compare domain names effectiveness

Tags: domains, url, multiple-domains, business

I have a business, it's not purely online, but its presence is mainly online.

I have purchased different domain names which I liked. Is there any service that allows you to compare their effectiveness attracting customers? I want to choose the one that will be more successful in making the customer click on my ads or my website as a search result or simply evokes a better service or sounds more nicely.

How can I go about this in a scientific manner, with no assumptions, without spending lots of money and time?

EDIT: By spending money and time I mean the most natural solution, which would be to replicate content on each (dangerous as google will penalise their ranking) and then run identical adwords campaigns for each, and see what happens. This would be very expensive, time costly and probably terrible for SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand the question.  You have two different domain names but they do not currently have any traffic to them?

Are you deciding which domain of the two to use and start building your site to?

you can track the natural traffic to the two domains by parking both of them and tracking the traffic that goes to each domain.

If the site is already built then A/B testing is the way.

Its very hard to say without knowing the two domain names and exactly where you are in the site building process..

Comment: But to do AB testing they would have to have the same content. That is detrimental to google search ranking.

Comment: Long Duplicate content is general bad for SEO. Short term duplicate content to do A/B testing should not really hurt SEO, long term.   The cost/benefit of A/B testing the same content outweighs any short term SEO hit, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Do [A/B Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). Look into using [Google Contents Experiments](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/06/helping-to-create-better-websites.html).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Contents Experiments. I have been reading about it now but it seems it doesn't help to test different websites with different URLs against each other.

Answer (score 0):

I can comment yet here, so I'll post here.

The thing with A/B tests, is that they are a good option for other kind of analysis, like better wording, colour, timing, mood acceptance of characteristics, etc, but not for deciding if, for instance, .com is better than .co.uk.

Google contents is something I'll have to read more to be able to talk about, for now, seems interesting.

So, moving on to your question. To really know which domain name might work better from the beginning, is crucial to know your target, age, country, how literate they are, how susceptible to marketing, how similar your domain is to competitors or famous brands, etc etc.

I'd say, that the best way so far, is to provide as much information as you can to an expert, be willing to talk and answer questions and then, decide.

Of course you can do that here and you will get some answer, some may be good, deep and convincing and others may go for the .com is better, which in itself, and as a generic thing, is usually true.

Good luck

Bye